# Why $(d+1)^{2T}{4T+R \choose R}e^{-2R+14T} \le \epsilon$ given $R=cT \ln d + \ln \frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Tags: probability, analysis

I read a paper and I found that the only step I don't understand is this derivation from 
$$R=c T \ln d + \ln \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\\text{to}\qquad (d+1)^{2T}{4T+R \choose R}e^{-2R+14T} \le \epsilon$$

Here $d$ is a constant integer, $c$ is a constant, $T$ is a positive integer, and $epsilon$ should be a small positive number. I'm not sure how the derivation follows, can someone help me?

This step appears near the bottom of page 23 in [this paper](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/steal.pdf).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try substituting $R$ in the exponential in the second expression? It  looks like there is a $d^c$ term in the denominator. The choose term is bounded as $c$ grows. Note also the paper says $c$ is a sufficiently large constant, not just an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Hi @snarfblaat, thanks for the comment. I did try to substitute it into it but can't get too far. May I know why is the choose term bounded as $c$ grows? For the $d^c$ term in the denominator, I guess you are referring to $e^{-2R} = e^{-2cT \ln d + ...} = d^{-2cT} ... $, by intuition I can see that it's a very big and important term, but then how can I use it? For example, not sure if I can or how can I combine it with $(d+1)^{2T}$. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Figured out more but am still not sure if it works our all right. My current deduction is as follows. Using the bound of binomial coefficients, we have $< (d+1)^{2T} (\frac{4T+R}{R}e)^R e^{-2R+14T} = (d+1)^{2T} (\frac{4T+R}{eR})^R e^{-14T}$. We can argue the $\frac{4T+R}{eR} \approx \frac{1}{e}$ when $c$ is large enough. This gives $\approx (d+1)^{2T} e^{-R+14T} = (d+1)^{2T} e^{ - cT\ln d - \ln (1/\epsilon) + 14T }$ which is smaller than $e^{- \ln (1/ \epsilon)} = \epsilon$ if $c$ if sufficiently large. Seems like the only part doesn't add up is the $\frac{4T+R}{eR} \approx \frac{1}{e}$ part

Comment: (continue) I mean ideally I want to bound it as $ < \frac{1}{e}$ but seems like I can only get $\frac{4T+R}{eR} \approx \frac{1}{e}$ when $c$ is sufficiently enough. Is there anything I didn't wrong?